# Running Low on Limestone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-blades

Of all the building materials available in Elder Scrolls Blades, I seem to be always running low on limestone. I've got a veritable boon of lumber and iron, but when it comes to limestone, I'm always waiting around to get some.

How can I efficiently earn/find limestone? Should I keep doing Jobs, waiting for one that eventually provides +7-10 limestone as a reward?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end of the day, the game is a freemium and they need to make money somehow and they decided to limit Limestone so you either grind or buy material packs with real money.

But to answer your question, there's no sure-fire way, you just have to pray you get jobs that give Limestone.

You probably already know this but Limestone drops from Wooden Chests, from Vases and Skeletons during Jobs.

Comment: It's free to play, not freeware. Freeware implies the game is completely free and never asks for monex.

Comment: @Dulkan Meant to write freemium, edited my post.

Comment: Something to note, this is for all resources, not just limestone. But, once you can build the workshop (town level 3), you have yet another random source that you can purchase from. Don't forget the daily reward also, this also has a chance to give resources. (And.. the Abyss to get chests)

Comment: @GameLikeBeaker If you want to make that an answer, you should. I ended up doing enough quests with a limestone reward to build the Workshop, which sells the resources you need. Xander your answer is still good though!

Comment: @Kaizerwolf done! I really love this game, can't wait to see more

Comment: @GameLikeBeaker That's right, I saw your comment just now sadly but you could just have edited that into my reply

Answer (score 3):

To extend on Xander's answer:

You can also build the workshop after your town has reached level 3. The workshop will provide a random set of materials that you can buy for a price. Since gold is easier to get than materials, this is also a good way to stock up. As you level up your workshop more items will become available for purchase.

You also have the daily reward that gives chests and resources.

Not only that but you get rewards from doing the abyss. I've seen limestone, copper, iron, chests and more.